# PHP SELECT * FROM not working correctly

Tags: php, database, pdo, prepared-statement, prepare

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
# Connection:
      require('config.php');
      $MyConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=x;dbname=x', $dbusername, $dbpassword);
      $MyConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      # Collecting:
      $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
      $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
      $lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']);
      $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);

      # Checking:
      $findUser = $MyConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 
        Username = :username OR Email = :email LIMIT 2");
      $findUser->bindParam(':username', $username);
      $findUser->bindParam(':email', $email);
      $findUser->execute();
      $foundUser = $findUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

      if($foundUser->Username == $username) {
        echo '
          <div id="pop-up" class="error">
          This username is already in use. Please choose another one.
          </div>
          ';
      }
      elseif ($foundUser->Email == $email) {
        echo '
          <div id="pop-up" class="error">
          This email address is already in use. Please choose another one. <br />
          If you think this is impossible, please
          <a href="http://www.askmephilosophy.co.nf/contact.php">contact us</a>.
          </div>
          ';
```

Whenever I try to register a new account I get sent to an error page, pre-set by the host. So I get a 404 error. I'm very sure the problem lays in the

```
$findUser = $MyConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = :username OR Email = :email LIMIT 2");
```

What am I doing wrong in that bit of code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code, visibly. Certainly nothing that would cause a 404 error (HTTP not found)

Comment: What does seem off is the use of `htmlspecialchars()` . If the username in the database is `user<abc` the result of that sent to the SELECT query will be `user&lt;abc`, which is likely wrong.  Hopefully you aren't calling `htmlspecialchars()` before `INSERT`.

Comment: Do you have an error log you can view on your host? If for some weird reason they're sending a PHP error to a 404 instead of 500, hopefully you would find it there.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, Thanks for pointing that out. Though that should not be causing the problem, you are indeed right about that. I should have to find another way around XSS.

Comment: @JesseDijkstra That's an appropriate way around XSS, but should only be used for _output_, never for input.  Data should be stored in the DB in its original state.

Comment: check your url maybe problem be there

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, They don't include an error log for free users of their hosting service.

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian, That seems very unlikely. I'm using a Register() function. So whenever I get an if(isset($_POST['submit-register']) it runs the code seen in my question.

Comment: There is no XSS danger here. The only danger could be SQL injection but as you use PDO and prepared statements, you are ok.

Comment: Though this still doesn't solve my problem of having a 404-error. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: If you have access to an error log, there might be information in there about what went wrong.

Comment: @Ikke, as I said before " 
"at"MichaelBerkowski, They don't include an error log for free users of their hosting service."

Comment: Are you sure that your form is posting to the URL you think it is? Without an error log people are going to be shooting into the dark, and that's not a fun game!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 error is from a **file not found**.

Such as

```
<a href="http://www.askmephilosophy.co.nf/contact.php">contact us</a>.
```

File `http://www.askmephilosophy.co.nf/contact.php` does not exist.

There must be some other file that does not exist in some part of the code you don't show (in the else after elseif ?) . Could be called if both Username and Email are free.

As most of links in `http://www.askmephilosophy.co.nf` cause 404 error you are heaping up trouble for yourself.

All links should be to real files. Until the content is available these *Stub* files should have a message like "Under Construction" and name of file etc.

Comment: I've removed all links to that file, and it still gives me an error. Besides, why would it cause an error? The user is not directly send towards that file. It's an option to click on.

Comment: There must be some other file that does not exist in some part of the code you don't show(else after elseif ?) . Could be called if both Username and Email are free.